# How to plot a line with only a numeric variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the data frame (csv file)

```
   Estación pH Conductividad
1        N1  6            29
2        N2  4            23
3        N3  2            16
4        N4  8            16
5        N5  3            20
6        N6  5            22
7        N7  8            27
8        N8  2            10
9        N9  3            27
10      N10  8            27
11      N11  8            26
12      N12  8            12
13      N13  2            19
14      N14  3            30
15      N15  5            25
16      N16  1            16
17      N17  1            17
18      N18  5            16
19      N19  8            15
20      N20  6            14
```

This is the code I have been using:

```
library(ggplot2)

pl <- ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=Estación, y = pH))

print(pl)
```

This is the plot

[image]

I need to add a line which follows the same position of the points..

How would I do that?

Comment: Are you after `ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=Estación, y = pH)) + geom_line()`?

Comment: I believe you mean the the X values are in the wrong order too? They're sorted alphabetically: `N1, N10, ...`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
df %>%
    mutate(Estacion = factor(Estacion, levels = paste0("N", 1:nrow(df)))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(Estacion, pH, group = 1)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Explanation: We ensure proper ordering of `x` values by re-levelling the `factor` variable `Estacion`; since `x` is a categorical variable, we need to tell `ggplot` that points belong to the same group using the `group` aesthetic so that points belonging to the same group can be connected with a line.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "   Estacion pH Conductividad
1        N1  6            29
2        N2  4            23
3        N3  2            16
4        N4  8            16
5        N5  3            20
6        N6  5            22
7        N7  8            27
8        N8  2            10
9        N9  3            27
10      N10  8            27
11      N11  8            26
12      N12  8            12
13      N13  2            19
14      N14  3            30
15      N15  5            25
16      N16  1            16
17      N17  1            17
18      N18  5            16
19      N19  8            15
20      N20  6            14");
```

Comment: Is there another way to tell R the order of "Estación" I want to show? I mean withouth doing ("N", 1:nrow(df)) because in the future I may have other kind of categorical names and I wouldn't know how to code them..

Comment: This works:
mutate = (Estación2 = factor(tf$Estación, levels = tf$Estación[1:nrow(tf)]))
pl <- ggplot(tf, aes(Estación2, pH, group = 1)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
print(pl)

Comment: @AlvaroMorales Since you've figured it out already my comment is somewhat redundant. But in general, you can control the order of categorical (i.e. `factor`) variables, by changing the order of the `factor` levels.

Comment: Yes, and I have improved the code a little bit:

tf <- read.csv('Practica1.csv', sep = ';', header = T)

tf$Estación = factor(tf$Estación, levels = tf$Estación[1:nrow(tf)], ordered = TRUE)

pl <- ggplot(tf, aes(Estación, pH, group = 1)) + geom_point() + geom_line()

print(pl)

Comment: in the past I didn't understand how to apply the group, now I know that group = 1 tell R that every point belongs with the same group, so plot the line with all of them..now I ask you :does "1" as in "group = 1"  mean something? or It's just the way to group them all.?

Comment: @AlvaroMorales Yes, `group=1` just assigns a random group label (`1`) to all observations